# How to properly time MPI code

Tags: c++, performance, mpi, timing

I have an MPI code (written by someone else) that I need to time. The basic layout of the code is as follows. In a nutshell, the code does a parallel SVD solve of a matrix `A` in two parts: (1) It first splits the matrix `A` evenly among `n` processors, and then (2) performs the SVD solve:

```
int main(){

    1. Code to split A among the different processors...

    2. actual parallel SVD solve 

}
```

I want to time only part (2) of the code (the SVD solve after A is distributed among the processors). I tried the following, but I am not sure if the output is right:

```
int main(){

    1. Code to split A among the different processors...

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double start = MPI_Wtime();

    2. actual parallel SVD solve 

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    double end = MPI_Wtime();

    if (MyPID == 0){ cout << end - start << endl;}
}
```

I am pretty new to MPI and not sure if I am using the MPI_Barrier command correctly, or if I really even need it. Will the output time correctly ignore the time it takes for part (1)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, all you want to do a distributed SVD. Have you looked at the linear algebra library [**ScaLAPACK**](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/)? With its [commands for singular value decomposition](http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node64.html), it should do exactly, what you need.

As to your use of `MPI_Barrier`: There is not much to it: All processes on the passed communicator wait until every other process on that communicator reach this line of code. However `MPI_Barrier` does not guarantee you that execution after the barrier is synchronised. For one, the performance of each process varies slightly even if executed on the same CPU type because of interrupts and secondly, there are miniscule differences in time when the execution is resumed after `MPI_Barrier`. Overall, you should avoid `MPI_Barrier` when ever possible. I see it as more of a debugging tool than something one would want to see in production code. Also: you do not need `MPI_Barrier` when you plan on using collective communication.

One last sentence to your overall design: It is often a mistake beginners in MPI make, that they think it is useful to have one *master process* which manages all the information and distributes problems to worker nodes. However, this design does imply a lot of communication and synchronisation. Communication (especially between computers) is comparatively slow and should be avoided at all costs. A more beneficial approach is often a *flat* design where every process chews along on its own part of the problem.

**edit:** only saw the line about `MPI_Wtime` just now: That code snippet seems to be correct. For another example, you could look at [this tutorial](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Wtime.html). If the sole purpose of this program is to measure the timing, I guess the first `MPI_Barrier` is somewhat viable, but the second is certainly not. Why would you have to syncronise your processes before stopping the timing? `MPI_Wtime` is local to the process that is executing it.

One more thing: If you have access to [**VampirTrace**](http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/vampirtrace) (ask your cluster administrator) you can do a much deeper analysis and get pretty graphs:

[image: example of the VampirTrace gui]

p.s.: can anyone suggest a free variant of VampirTrace?

Comment: niklasfi, there was russian project `openvampir`: https://bitbucket.org/hpcc_kpi/openvampir/wiki/Home but I didn't check it. Also I think that most MPI has builtin tracing, e.g. MPICH has `jumpshot`s: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/perfvis/software/viewers/ And OpenMPI's FAQ says http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=perftools#view-VT that TUD has free converter from Vampir's OTF to LaTeX at http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/otf